# BOE Universe @prompt with null value

Tags: universe

I need to have a null value in a prompt for in my BOE Universe.  How do I do this?

```
@Prompt('Special Claims Indicator','A','Special Claims Analytics\Special Claim Type Code',MULTI,CONSTRAINED,,{' '})
```

When I change my prompt value of ' ' to null or '' my error is `Parse Failed: Invalid definition (UNV0023). Error parsing default values parameter (7th parameter)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging:
 "Note: you cannot use the operators NULL and Not NULL when creating prompted filters. "
http://reports.is.ed.ac.uk/areas/itservices/busintel/TrainingMaterials/advUser/Lesson2-Step4.html